# jquery.numberformatter: with precision, format number incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3` to format number, and I ran into some issue here. The code is as below. `f` is my number.

```
$.formatNumber(f, {format:formatStr, locale:"us"});
```

so my `formatStr` is as below `#,###.00`, and if `f=28.567`, then the result is `28.57` which is correct. But if `f=5000000`, the the result is `50.00` which is incorrect. It should be `5000000.00`. Please help what did I do wrong here.

For the case of `f=5000000`, if my `formatStr=#,###`, then my result is `5,000,000`, which is correct, so this has to do which the precision that I set.

**NOTE**: I have jshashtable-2.1.js in my resource

Comment: Try other values: 128.567, 1128.567, 111128.567, 500000, 5000, 50. To find the envelope of the problem